# Using Mutual Authentication and I receive 403 Forbidden error from Salesforce API

Tags: authentication, java, ssl, wsc

I have set up Mutual Authentication on my Salesforce org so that my project can use two ways SSL with Salesforce. Here are my steps:

1- I use a CA sign certificate (GoDaddy) and upload it to the `Set Up > Certificate and Key Management > Mutual Authentication Certificates` section
[image]

2- I create a new `Permission Set` entry and select the option `Enforce SSL/TLS Mutual Authentication`
[image]

3- Then I create a new `API Only User` and assign that `Permission Set` entry to it.
[image]

4- Next, in my project, I create a Keystore (JKS) that contains the client certificate (it is exactly the same as the one I uploaded to `Salesforce Mutual Authentication Certificates` at the first step). Its structure looks like this.

[image]

5- I use `soapUI` tool to verify the `Mutual Authentication` settings. I need to confirm if it works correctly or not.

5.1- I configure the `soapUI` tool to use the client keystore in `Preferences > SSL Settings` section.
[image]

5.2- I also load the `Enterprise WSDL` that I generated from my org into the tool. Then, I use the `login` request in the WSDL and enter the username and password of the `Only API User` account created at step `#3` and I receive its `sessionId` successfully.
[image]

5.3- Next, I use this `sessionId` and send another query request e.g. query `Account` data and it works.

[image]

Now, I can confirm the `Mutual Authentication` is configured correctly and be able to work with `soapUI`!

6- Back to my project, I use `Salesforce Web Service Connector (WSC) v53` library. I do the same step `5.1` to send the username and password of the `Only API User` and I can get its `sessionID` too.

7- Then, I use this `sessionID` and send another request to perform calling the describe `User sObject`. But, it returns `403: Forbidden` error message.

Currently, I am stuck here. I have not known what the root cause is. Below is the captured image at the time I received the `403` error code.

Is there something I was missed? Please advise me!

[image]

```
 {GET /services/data/v53.0/sobjects/User/describe/ HTTP/1.1: null}
 {User-Agent: Salesforce Web Service Connector For Java/1.0}
 {Authorization: Bearer 00D0S0000009JwRxxxx.....}
 {Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8}
 {Accept: application/json}
 {Accept-Charset: UTF-8}
 {X-Pretty-Print: 1}
 {Host: xxxx--xxxx.my.salesforce.com:8443}
 {Connection: keep-alive}
```

Comment: Are you using the exact same user account in both scenarios? If the same user account, then likely issue is still permissions related. Your test case with SoapUI uses Account and whatever query and your 2nd test is a describe on the User. Try the same Account query in the WSC scenario. FYI, WSC is quite old. There are a ton of modern SOAP clients for Java, you'd be better with one of those.